com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException | Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $

I'm encountering the following problem when sending an API request on my Android 10 device. The response to the request I sent to the API returns as follows:

Actually, I am facing a crash issue directly on the application login screen without sending an API request. My other API service classes are as follows:


When I tested on a version 13 Android phone, I did not encounter any crashes.
This is the crash message: 
 
Thank you very much in advance :)

Please try to debug your app or temporarily set up logging to find out what data your app is actually receiving. For example, maybe it doesn't receive JSON but an HTML error page.

Unrelated to this, but you should probably use a JSON library to create the JSON string in LoggBeeAPIService#login instead of creating it by hand. Otherwise if users have for example " in their password, it will break the JSON string and they are unable to log in.
